# Vim: <Ctrl-h|j|k|l> for Movement in Insert Mode

Tags: vim, insert, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm being quite new to Vim and I consider setting it up so I can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + movement keys (<kbd>H</kbd>, <kbd>J</kbd>, <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>L</kbd>) for moving around in Insert mode.

Two questions:

1. How is this set in `.vimrc`?
2. Is this recommendable (at least the slightest considerable), or just plain 'backwards'?

Comment: You can, of course, do this, but it is not what insert mode is for. In insert mode you are supposed to insert text. Only insert text, not move around, it is a job for normal mode. I suggest you limit all insert-mode motions to just one-line ones: for other moves normal mode is more *convenient*, but switching to normal mode just to move one character/word back is too much for me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can achieve what you want with these mappings:

```
inoremap <c-k> <up>
inoremap <c-j> <down>
inoremap <c-h> <left>
inoremap <c-l> <right>
```

I don't see anything really wrong with it, although you obviously lose the existing mappings (e.g. `<c-l>` to redraw the screen.

Vi purists will probably baulk at the idea of staying in insert mode whilst navigating around your file, but there are worse sins.

Comment: Worse sins indeed, like having to hold `Ctrl` to move around a file.

Comment: This works great. I've remapped Caps-Lock key to be Ctrl. This means I can easily move my pinky finger 1cm to the left of the 'a' key and then move with H,J,K,L in Insert Mode. If there's ANY more ergonomic way to move in insert mode, I'd be happy to know. Otherwise, I don't get the argument that one shouldn't move in Insert mode, just for the sake of 'not moving in insert mode', or, that's what Normal mode is for. Why? Why not be able to move the cursor in BOTH Insert AND Normal mode? Isn't Vim supposed to be easy on your fingers, having you type less to accomplish more? :)

Comment: I also mapped <C-Space> to switch modes. Essentially, keeping my pinky finger always on Caps-Lock (i.e. Ctrl key).

Comment: Sorry to comment on such an old answer, but, on my terminal, this solution breaks `Shift+Backspace` as it's mapped to `^H`.

Answer (score 21):

Did you know that CTRL-O in insert mode temporarily switches to normal mode for one normal-mode command? So, CTRL-O j, CTRL-O k, etc. But also CTRL-O ^, etc.

Comment: +1 to this, never knew that, normal command are so powerful you really only need to use one to go most places. "<CTRL-O> 2k" will be used a lot by me.

Answer (score 7):

People already told you how to do this, so I just want to answer the second part of your question.

I don't quite get the point of using Vim and not using the power of modes. The main problem with this setup is that you are limiting your movement power to "one character in any direction". This is not "wrong", this is just inefficient. What about `F`, `f`, `T`, `t` (moving forward/backward to a char)? What about `0` and `$` (moving to the beginning and the end of line)? What about paragraph/sentence movements (`[]{}`)? What about going to the matching parens (`%`)? Etc, etc, etc.

IMO, it is better to learn to use the full power of normal mode movements, than to reduce your movement abilities to `hjkl`

Comment: For what it's worth, I completely agree with you. When I posted my answer I assumed that the OP wanted the possibility for the cases where it's certainly quicker to press `<C-l>` than `<ESC>la`.

Comment: I mainly wanted the possibility to move to previous/next line from the current one, but also left and right (using Ctrl + home row movement keys).

Comment: Moving only once character whit ctrl+hjkl is fine, when you r at the wrong side of " or ()